# Java modulo doesn't work with large numbers

Tags: java, modulo

I am creating a program to calculate [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) in Java. While doing so, I noticed that the modulo `%` operator doesn't function properly when dealing with large numbers.

Here is my code:

```
double a = 2305843009213693951d; //2^61 -1
double b = 2;
double m = a % b; //this should be 1.0
System.out.println(m); //prints 0.0
```

While one would expect the result to be 1, since the original number isn't even, it actually returns `0.0`.
Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Change `double` to `long`

Comment: or even better to BigInteger